# GetKeyboardState return wrong result

Tags: c++, winapi

i use win7 64bit.
i use GetKeyboardState() to get keyboard state.

```
BYTE keyState[256];
GetKeyboardState(keyState);
BOOL leftButtonClicked = GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON);
```

if click inside the main wnd, every thing is ok, but if click outside the main wnd, the leftButtonClicked is still true.

the msdn said,

> An application can call this function to retrieve the current status of all the virtual keys. The status changes as a thread removes keyboard messages from its message queue. The status does not change as keyboard messages are posted to the thread's message queue, nor does it change as keyboard messages are posted to or retrieved from message queues of other threads.

but main wnd don't receive WM_LBUTTONDOWN, so why this function get wrong result?
or i misunderstood something?

thanks.

Comment: It's not "wrong result", it's "You haven't checked where the mouse is" - you only get VM_LBUTTONDOWN when something it happens within your window. But the GetKeyState is universal - it tells you what the sate is at the point of asking, whether it's relevant to your window or not is up to your application to determine.

Comment: I'm confused. You never look at the result of GetKeyboardState.

Answer (score 2):

GetKeyboardState and GetKeyState return the *buffered* state of the keyboard and mouse.  Stored when the last input event was entered into the message queue.  An important feature, the message can stay stored in the queue for a while if the program isn't pumping messages.

When you click outside the window, the input event that generates goes to whatever queue that's associated with the window you clicked on.  Not the queue of your program.  Accordingly, the keyboard state doesn't change.

You'll need to use GetAsyncKeyState() to obtain the current state.